# React Redux - Waiting for async api call to finish before next action is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a web app that uses React + Redux, with a backend using Django (DRF). I am using axios to send in my API request, which is asynchronous. The issue I am facing right now is that the actions dispatched do not wait for the API call to finish before the next action is dispatched. Below is my code

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    success: id => {
        dispatch(fetchSalesProject(id));
        dispatch(createMessage('Requirement successfully updated!'))
    }
})
```

fetchSalesProject action (axiosInstance is just a custom modification of axios call, the functionality is the same)

```
export const fetchSalesProject = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    console.log('enter sales project action')
    axiosInstance
        .get(`/sales-project/detail/${id}/`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('fetched data')
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_SALES_PROJECT,
                payload: res.data,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

createMessage action

```
export const createMessage = (message) => {
  console.log('message')
  return {
    type: CREATE_MESSAGE,
    message: message,
  };
};
```

When calling this.props.success (refer to mapDispatchToProps), the message is displayed before the api call response data is received (evident by the fact that console.log('message') runs before console.log('fetched data'))

I would want the data to be fetched from the api call before i run the createMessage action, is there any advise on how to accomplish that? I am new to React and especially Redux, so hope that you guys can point me in the right direction on how to accomplish that.

Also, can I check whether it is wrong to have a dispatch in the mapDispatchToProps, and also a dispatch within the action (refer to fetchSalesProject action). Would it cause any issues with performance or is it frowned upon to do so? Please advise me as I am quite confused with Redux.

Thanks all for reading through, all help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while you are dispatching from UI, you just sending an object towards reducer which in his turn will modify the state at the store and in the end of the process will re-render components that refer to props that changed. At the moment you are dispatching the first action, there is nothing that tells the component that it should wait before sending the next object to the reducer

So you have 2 options,

the first is at UI itself use `componentDidUpdate` or `useEffect` for run the second action after the first action reduced

---

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if (prevProps.salesProject != this.props.salesProject)
         dispatch(createMessage('Requirement successfully updated!'))
      }
```

---

while I assume that `dispatch(fetchSalesProject(id));` modify `salesProject` prop

Another way to do that, and in case you actually fine with that `message` and `salesProject` will gonna get together to the reducer, is to dispatch them in one action

---

```
 export const fetchSalesProjectAndMessage = (id, message) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log('enter sales project action')
  axiosInstance
    .get(`/sales-project/detail/${id}/`)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('fetched data')
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_SALES_PROJECT_AND_MESSAGE,
            payload: { data: res.data, message }
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
 };
```

---

and at reducer `payload.data` either `payload.message` will refer to desired info

Comment: thanks so much for the reply, both options work, but i think i will go with the first option, as there might be times where i need to fetch the sales project data without any message, and i assume that it would be more messy if i tried to handle for that along with the second option. but thanks once again, really appreciate the answer! will implement the first option :-)

Comment: @HagaiHarari When you dispatch a thunk action and the thunk action returns a promise you can wait for it: `const createThunkAction = arg => dispatch => {do stuff;dispatch(stuff);return Promise}` You can now **wait** for the action: `dispatch(createThunkAction(arg)).then(()=>thunk action is done)`

Comment: you are waiting at the action itself, and if it is ok with the person who wrote the question I think that the second approach that I suggested is cleaner then your code, but indeed your code gonna work too, and anyhow thanks for the info and the tip :)

Comment: The reason I added this is because the question was `React Redux - Waiting for async api call to finish before next action is dispatched` If someone in the future finds this question and gets `you should combine your actions into one` then that doesn't realy ansewr the question. Say I have async actions A, B and C and sometimes I would like to only do A, other times A then B, or A then C or only C or C and then A or C .... Combining the actions into one is not an option. In that case you can solve it in mapdispatch: `dispatch(a).then(b)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way of doing this that does not force you combine two action creators. When your thunk action creator returns a promise then you can wait for it. Your current code did not return the axios promise but if you do return it you can do the following:\

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  success: (id) => {
    dispatch(fetchSalesProject(id)).then(() =>
      dispatch(//wait for fetchSalesProject to finish
        createMessage('Requirement successfully updated!')
      )
    );
  },
});

export const fetchSalesProject = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log('enter sales project action');
  return axiosInstance //you did not return anything here
    .get(`/sales-project/detail/${id}/`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('fetched data');
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_SALES_PROJECT,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)
      );
      //return rejected promise here
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i am not too familiar with promises, but does that mean that i am able to use promises to wait for the axios call to complete, before dispatching this action along with another action (the showMessage action) ? by the way, i was looking into redux saga, and i was wondering if you would know if redux saga would be able to address my problem better?

Comment: @jason Redux saga would make it a lot more complicated to address your problem. If axiosInstance.get returns a promise (and it likely does because it returns something that has a then property that is a function) then you can **return** that from your action creator as I did in the answer to wait for the action to finish (as I did in my answer).

Comment: alright, then i'll stick to redux-thunk instead and look into using your answer, thank you for the help, really appreciate it :-)